# JQuery post JSON object to a server

Tags: jquery, json

I create a json that needs to be posted in jersey, a server running by grizzly that has a REST webservice gets incoming json object which need to be outputed. I'm giving a try but not sure how to implement this correctly.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import javax.ws.rs.*;

    @Path("/helloworld")
    public class GetData {
        @GET
        @Consumes("application/json")
        public String getResource() {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            String result = obj.getString("name");

            return result;      
        }                   

    }
```

i have a html file that runs this method while onload

```
    function sendData() {
        $.ajax({
                url: '/helloworld',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    name:"Bob",


                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
            alert("json posted!");
        };
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To send json to the server, you first have to create json

```
function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/helloworld',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            name:"Bob",
            ...
        }),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

This is how you would structure the ajax request to send the json as a post var.

```
function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/helloworld',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { json: JSON.stringify({
            name:"Bob",
            ...
        })},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

The json will now be in the `json` post var.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still figuring out how the server get the json object.

Comment: When sent in this way, the json will be the request body. If you instead want the json to be in a POST var, the ajax request will need to be modified.

Comment: But what if I want to Json object as it. i.e. Suppose I have JSONObject created using jsp and want to pass to next page then how to send JSONObject (jsonobj) in jquery POST

Comment: @Optimus both ways do send the jsonobject in a post request. With the first, the jsonstring will be in the request body of the post request, and the second the jsonstring will be in a post variable named "json"

Comment: Note that dataType specifies the expected format of the *response* from the server; it is unrelated to the format of data being sent to the server.

Comment: as far as I can see, this is incomplete. In order to receive proper JSON on my node server, I also have to add: "contentType":  'application/json; charset=utf-8',

Comment: only because your body parser doesn’t detect without it. but it’s not. a bad idea to have it

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to use `FormData()`. But you need to set `contentType` as `false`:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('name', 'Bob'); 

function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/helloworld',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```