# JSON returning null values using WCF Services

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, datacontractserializer

Hi all I am new in JSON and WCF Services. I am trying to call wcf service using JSON and my paramater is one of my data contract class.

Here is my Data Contract Class.

```
namespace Employee.Services.DataContracts
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class ReqDataContract
    {
[DataMember]
        public long Type { get; set; }
[DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }
[DataMember]
        public DateTime? FDate { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public long? UserID { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Here is myWCF Service function

```
public void SaveRequ(ReqDataContract request)
        {
            var req=request;
        }
```

Here is Interface Implementation

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [return: MessageParameter(Name = "ReqData")]
void SaveRequ(ReqDataContract request);
```

.js File (AJAX Call)

```
var selection = "{ \"Type\": 55,\"ID\":'test@yahoo.com' ,\"FDate\":" + null + " ,\"UserID\": 'ASDAS'}";
searchData = searchData + (searchData != '' ? "," : "") + selection;
    if (searchData != null) {
        searchData = "[" + searchData + "]";
    }
var searchJSON = jQuery.toJSON(eval("(" + searchData + ")"));
    var strJSON = searchJSON.toString();

    params = '{\"request\":' + strJSON + '}';
    $.ajax({
        async: false, //To perform synchronize operation to get status
        type: "POST",
        url: servicePath + "SaveRequ",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: params,
        processData: true,
        success: function (data) {
          //  alert(data.ReqData);
        },
        error: function (xhr, result, id) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
    });
```

Everything works fine but the problem is i ma getting all the value null in **request** parameter....Am i missing something?? Please help me in this.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110805/jquery-post-json-object-to-a-server to pass an object to server in Json format.

Answer (score 3):

Did this get resolved?  If not, for fdate try a valid value instead of NULL and see if that works.  JSON.NET might be a better solution for processing null from JSON into objects.