# Pass value of Javascript variable to MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to pass area name selected from drop down menu to query of MySQL through PHP. I retrieved name in JavaScript but I am unable to store value from JavaScript to PHP. My Code is As follows

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function getIndex()
        {
            var x=document.getElementById("cmbArea").selectedIndex;
            var y=document.getElementById("cmbArea").options

            var z= y[x].text;
            alert(z); 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name ="form1" action="Demo1.php" method="post">
    <select id="cmbArea" name="cmbArea">
    <?php
    include 'Connect.php';
    $query = "SELECT varAreaName FROM tbArea" ;
    $result = mysql_query($query);       
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['varAreaName'].'">' . $row['varAreaName'] . '</option>';   
    }

    ?>
    </select>
    </form>
    <input type="Button" onclick="getIndex()" value="Alert index of selected option">

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: This is the HTML/PHP that creates the form (and its select) that posts the data to PHP. We need to see the other side that picks up the $_POST

Comment: You'll need to submit the form to read the value up on the server.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they're deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). Moreover, can you show your `Demo1.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your form. The value will be available in `$_POST['cmbArea']`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly I would use AJAX in this case.  Something like this: http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can not 'store' value from javascript to PHP, as javascript is in client-side(literally in your Browser-side), not in the server-side.

You need to post the data using ajax(Jquery ajax may be), and post them in JSON format.
[Check this thread..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110805/jquery-post-json-object-to-a-server)

Answer (score 0):

PHP will run on server and then javascript will be run on the browser. So you cannot do both in the same page, as you try.

I think the best way is to submit the form, and read the value there using PHP. There you can execute your query.

If you don't want to submit you can check AJAX which will send an asynchronous server side request, without refreshing the webpage.