# pass Javascript variables to an Arraylist (java servlet)

Tags: java, javascript, arraylist

for example,

i have a table :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>john</td>
<td>doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

- which can be dynamically created.

i'm getting the values from the table by :

```
table.find('tr').each(function(i){
    var $tds = $(this).find('td input');
    var a = $tds.eq(0).val();
    var b = $tds.eq(1).val();
    alert(a +" " b);
}
```

How to put the values of this table into an `ArrayList`
or is it possible to put this on an  `ArrayList`?

Comment: You're talking about two completely separate technologies. Can you clarify the scope of the java code and the scope of the javascript code? Since you mentioned java-ee I'm guessing you mean JSP.

Comment: @Yaje What you posted does not include java, java-ee, jsp, servlets or arraylist. Java != JavaScript. It seems like you want a JavaScript array, maybe with jQuery?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i maybe lost with the terminologies here but my main goal is to put those `a` and `b` variable in an `ArrayList`. can it be done?

Comment: @Yaje JavaScript does not have ArrayList, it has arrays. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray), *The JavaScript Array global object is a constructor for arrays, which are high-level, list-like objects.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i know, the problem is i don't know how to pass variables of javascript to for example, a request to be caught by my servlet

Comment: You can look other topic [post JSON object to a server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110805/jquery-post-json-object-to-a-server

Comment: What is the code you're using to generate the table?

Comment: You can look other topic [post json object to server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110805/jquery-post-json-object-to-a-server
 Hope this help!

Comment: @Blaskovicz i use jQuery to generate it.

Comment: Let's take a step back here; what are you trying to do at a high level? Take data from the server and render it with javascript? Take the data from a page and send it back to the server?

Comment: @Blaskovicz yes. i do both. because once i got the data. i display it to the user and the user can manipulate the data(add,edit,delete). after the user has done so and hits save, i take the data again i send it to server for saving.

Comment: You need to give us more code in terms of how you're getting the data from the server; once you do this we will be able to help you with the code for getting the changes back to the server.

What web technology are you using - stock servlets? What version? Do you have jaxb enabled?

Comment: i'm passing the data from the servlet to jsp using `request` scope. and displaying it using `JSTL` w/ `JSEL`

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note that *JavaScript* runs on the front-end by an event trigger or on load (according to how it is engineered to behave), while *Java* is created and run on the server side (back-end), so when *Java* runs and finishes, there is no *javascript* running started yet.

The purpose of *Javascript* is to run and interact with the user in places where *Java* can't.

So in order to achieve this conversion to `ArrayList`, you need access to the server. This can be done through *[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)*.

Here are some Ajax-related links:

1. http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php
2. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: If he's using jsp he doesn't need to do an ajax call; the data he's talking about seems to be on the page he's on.

Comment: If your assumption is correct, then why does he need to convert it to Java in the first place.

Comment: @Blaskovicz Nice XD, let's see what comes out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = [];

table.find('tr td').each( function(i, element) { 
    newArray.push( element.val() ); 
}
```

Once you have a JavaScript array, you can pass the values via $.post to the server side.