# AJAX call with JSON array not getting triggered to server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json

Im trying to pass a json array using jquery ajax to my code behind.

**What worked**:

If I call my codebehind function using jQuery `.ajax()` with an empty json string (`"{}"`), my codebehind function is getting triggered without issue.

**What I am trying to do**:

If I put a Json string to the "data" property of jQuery `.ajax()` and then create a code behind function with a string parameter, it does not get triggered anymore.

Here's my code:

***Client side***

```
function SendAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/MyFunction",
        data: '{"foo":"bar"}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
           //DO Somtething
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            //DO Somtething
        }
    });
}
```

**Server side**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MyFunction(string jsonData)
{   
   //Do something
   return "test";
}
```

- My json array is correctly formatted
- I have a static function
- I have the `[WebMethod]`

Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery post JSON object to a server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110805/jquery-post-json-object-to-a-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 100% working

```
function SendAjax() {
            var city = "ABC";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default4.aspx/MyFunction",
                data: "{jsonData:" + JSON.stringify(city) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                   alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    //DO Somtething
                }
            });
        }




[WebMethod]
    public static string MyFunction(string jsonData)
    {
        //Do something
        return "test";
    }
```