# Node.JS post to JSON file not formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I am having issues with my ajax to node.js post to JSON file. It works properly, however it is not formatted properly I am assuming. Because when it reads the data, it does not come back due to what I assume is it thinks it is unreadable.

Here is the **AJAX** call:

```
postComment: function(commentJSON, success, error) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080',
    data: commentJSON,
    success: function(comment) {
      success(comment)
    },
    error: error
  });
},
```

Here is the **NODE.JS**:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  console.log('Request received: ');
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      console.log(data);
      fs.writeFile("comments-data.json", chunk, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
      })
    });
    res.end('{"msg": "success"}');
  };
  if (req.method == 'GET') {
    fs.readFile("comments-data.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.end(data)
      }
    })
  };
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

Here is how it writes to the file:

```
id=c1&parent=&created=2016-08-11T19%3A24%3A31.418Z&modified=2016-08-11T19%3A24%3A31.418Z&content=test&fullname=&profile_picture_url=https%3A%2F%2Fviima-app.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fmedia%2Fuser_profiles%2Fuser-icon.png&created_by_current_user=true&upvote_count=0&user_has_upvoted=false
```

Here is what my get request understands:

```
[
{  
"id": 1,
"parent": null,
"created": "2015-01-01",
"modified": "2015-01-01",
"content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed posuere interdum sem. Quisque ligula eros ullamcorper quis, lacinia quis facilisis sed sapien. Mauris varius diam vitae arcu.",
"fullname": "Simon Powell",
"profile_picture_url": "https://app.viima.com/static/media/user_profiles/user-icon.png",
"created_by_admin": false,
"created_by_current_user": false,
"upvote_count": 3,
"user_has_upvoted": false
}
]
```

Comment: What exactly does `commentJSON` contain?

Comment: possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110805/jquery-post-json-object-to-a-server/10110924#10110924

Comment: @KevinB It's a JQuery Plugin so it should read and write it's own data I would assume 
http://viima.github.io/jquery-comments/

Comment: Adding stringify to the data in the ajax appeared to help. However it does not come in as an array. Also it keeps overwriting the data in the file instead of adding to it

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple problems.

Comment: According to [the doco](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), `.writeFile()` "writes data to a file, **replacing the file** if it already exists". I think you're supposed to use `.open()` with the appropriate flags, and then `.write()`.

Answer (score -1):

Changing my ajax call to this made it readable for my get request. But it is overwriting the data in the JSON file. I would like it to just add to it.

```
                postComment: function(commentJSON, success, error) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: 'http://localhost:8080',
                            data: JSON.stringify([commentJSON]),
                            success: function(comment) {
                                success(comment)
                            },
                            error: error
                        });
                },
```

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to narrow it down to just the part about appending to the file.