# How to send multiple sets of interrelated data attributes though jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML:

```
<div data-id="2" data-width="100" class="column_heading column_name">Name</div>
<div data-id="4" data-width="90" class="column_heading column_name">Country</div>
<div data-id="6" data-width="110" class="column_heading column_name">Email</div>
<div data-id="7" data-width="100" class="column_heading column_name">Name</div>
<div data-id="8" data-width="120" class="column_heading column_name">Phone</div>
```

I want to send data attributes (`data-id="2"`, `data_width="100"`) for each div to the server through jQuery AJAX. How can it be achieved?

If I do like this:

```
columns = array();
$('.column_heading').each(function(){
    column = $(this).attr('data-id');
    columns.push(column);
})
```

And in jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/get-data-attr.php",
    cache: false,
    data: "columns="+columns,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response){
        $("#response").html(response);
    }
});
```

But how can I send second data attribute. How can I related these two sets of data attributes for each div and send it to the server side?

Comment: you can build a json object in javascript and post it via ajax. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110805/jquery-post-json-object-to-a-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try an array of objects.

```
columns = array();
    $('.column_heading').each(function(){
        column = $(this).attr('data-id');
        column = {id: $(this).attr('data-id'), width: $(this).attr('data-width') };
        columns.push(column);
    })
```

Then you can extract the value in this way:
columns[0].id

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp